# Coroutine vs Fiber difference clarification

Tags: coroutine, fiber

In the book `Linux System Programming, 2nd Edition`, the difference between coroutines and fiber is explained as follows:

> Coroutines and fibers provide a unit of execution even lighter in weight than the thread (with the former being their name when they are a programming language construct, and the latter when they are a system construct).

I have some example of Coroutines (language constructs) but unable to find the example of Fibers.

Can anyone provide me some example of Fiber (a system construct)?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You could take a look at [boost.coroutine2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/coroutine2/doc/html/index.html) and [boost.fiber](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/fiber/doc/html/index.html) (C++ libraries) - both use the same context switching mechanism ([callcc()/continuation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/context/doc/html/context/cc.html)) from [boost.context](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/context/doc/html/index.html).

In short - the difference between coroutines and fibers is, that the context switch between fibers is managed by a scheduler (selects the next fiber ...). Coroutines don't have a concept of a scheduler.

A more detailed explanation of the difference between coroutines and fibers can be read in [N4024: Distinguishing coroutines and fibers](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4024.pdf).

Comment: N4024 is an amazing explanation! Thank you for sharing this incredible resource.